# Does something like Gradle Wrapper exist for Terraform which works on Win, MacOS and Linux?

Tags: terraform

I am using Terraform on multiple projects on Windows and currently, I switch Terraform version manually using `choco`. Is there a self-contained solution like [Gradle Wrapper](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_wrapper.html), which auto-downloads and uses a specific Terraform version?

Was looking at `tfenv` but it says:

> Windows (64bit) - only tested in git-bash - currently presumed failing due to symlink issues in git-bash

and I am using Win64 and git-bash. Also it doesn't look like `tfenv` auto-downloads?

Answer (score 2):

There are several. I like "tfswitch".

https://tfswitch.warrensbox.com/

When you run `tfswitch` the tool will try to find version string in your Project or you can set it via ENVs.

Comment: Thanks, will give it a try